# Linux run-parts not working with php files

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) about cron jobs for linux. I want to use the `cron.hourly` folder to run php scripts. In the tutorial, it states that the folders are controlled by the script:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

I can easily run and test the script using:

```
$ /etc/cron.hourly/test.php
```

This works fine. But when I test the script:

```
$ run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

Nothing happens. Does **run-parts** work on php files?

`run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly` gives me nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default pattern for filenames is `(^_?([a-z0-9_.]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$)`

- Which means files such as `00-init` would match.
- Typically no file extensions (such as `.php`)

Hence either rename your files, or use `run-parts` with the `--regex='[\w\.]+'` option.

- Also check with `-v --list` what filenames get detected then.

Comment: So why can test.php can still run as a php file without .php extension? Thanks mario! I never knew I can get rid of the extension.

Comment: Well I assume you've made it executable and have the proper shebang `#!/usr/bin/php` already. In that case the file extension is generall redundant.  All of `.sh` or `.py` are just decoration as soon as a script is executable.

Comment: Yes, I have the #!/usr/bin/php. Thanks!